# Dynamic fields thymeleaf list iteration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I'm getting a really weird error! while iterating on list, thymeleaf identified index as a property of my bean and not an index value!

```
<div th:each="phoneStat : *{phones}">
    <select th:field="*{phones[__${phoneStat.index}__].variety}">
        <option></option>
    </select>
    <div class=" input-field col s4">
        <input class="validate" th:field="*{phones[__${phoneStat.index}__].number}"
               th:id="${'phonenumber-'+ phones[__${phoneStat.index}__]}" type="text"/>
        <label th:for="${'phonenumber-'+ phones[__${phoneStat.index}__]}"> Mobile</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong here? Please help!

```
2015-06-15 15:48:25.453 ERROR 7764 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "phoneStat.index" (/custom:89)] with root cause

org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:(pos 10): Property or field 'index' cannot be found on object of type 'com.ubleam.corporate.server.model.Phone' - maybe not public?
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually when binding fields to a form, in order to acces to a list with th:each as the [doc](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#iteration) specifies, we should use two variables `item` and `phoneStat`:

```
<div th:each="item, phoneStat : *{phones}">
    <select th:field="*{phones[__${phoneStat.index}__].variety}">
        <option></option>
    </select>
    <div class=" input-field col s4">
        <input class="validate" th:field="*{phones[__${phoneStat.index}__].number}"
               th:id="${'phonenumber-'+ phones[__${phoneStat.index}__]}" type="text"/>
        <label th:for="${'phonenumber-'+ phones[__${phoneStat.index}__]}"> Mobile</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Simple**

`th:each` returns the objects in the collection when you have 1 variable defined before the `th:each`. Not the object metadata. If you need the index, you have to use 2 variables.

http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#using-theach

---

**In detail**

Why do you use `{phones[__${phoneStat.index}__].number}` while `phoneStat` is actually the object of iteration.

You can simply do this as follows.

```
<div th:each="phone : *{phones}">
    <select th:field="${phone.variety}" >
        <option></option>
    </select>
    <div class="input-field col s4" >
        <label>Mobile</label>
        <input th:field="${phone.number}" type="text" class="validate"/> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Actually the th:each needed two variables like to acces to the index :

th:each="item, rowStat : *{phones}" 

When you use just one variable it take as an item an not as row, colon object ( array) so the index does exists

@Faraj-farouk http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html

Thanks you to you response :)

Comment: but your code only takes 1 value`<div th:each="phoneStat : *{phones}">`

Comment: You are right and that was the mistake i've done i used th:each with a single row variable while a shoud have to as i told you